# complex search and replace query (Sed or gsar for Windows)

Tags: search, sed, replace, command-line

I want to replace a certain word in a file with a hex-value, with the use of gsar.exe (command line!), but ignore it if the word is somewhere between quotes

Original text:
9023 AAAA "this is a AAAA" "AAAA" "*:;AAAA'" Aaaa " Because AAAA" " aaaa " AaAa

Text after gsar is done:
9023 XXXX "this is a AAAA" "AAAA" "*:;AAAA'" XXXX " Because AAAA" " aaaa " XXXX

(where XXXX represents the hex value a5)

Please note:

- it should be case insensitive
- it should ignore everything between quotes
- I want to use gsar.exe but sed.exe (Windows) or another command line tool would be good as well
- The opening quotes are the same character as the closing quotes (0x22)

I know this be done and probably with only 1 line. This is what makes it extra frustrating.
I hope there is some gsar/sed guru here that can help me out.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^/\n/;ta
        :a;s/\nAAAA/XXXX\n/i;ta;s/\n("[^"]*")/\1\n/;ta;s/\n(.)/\1\n/;ta
        s/.$//' file
```

Turn on extended regexp support `-E`.

Insert a newline as a marker at the start of the line.

Using the marker, work through the line looking for the required string and replace if necessary, skipping any double quoted strings.

At the end of the line, remove the introduced newline.

An alternative:

```
sed -E 's/"[^"]*"/\n&\n/g;:a;s/^([^"]*)AAAA/\1XXXX/img;ta;s/\n//g' file
```

It is interesting to note that the reverse solution may found by adding one character to one substitution.

```
sed -E 's/"[^"]*"/\n&\n/g;:a;s/^("[^"]*)AAAA/\1XXXX/img;ta;s/\n//g' file
```

All these solutions follow the same procedure; the erection of scaffolding, working on a new problem that incorporates the scaffolding and finally dismantling the scaffolding once the solution has been found.

The scaffolding in these cases is the introduction of newlines.

Comment: Hello Potong. Thank you so much for your time but I cannot get it to work. It probably has to do with the difference between the windows and linux version of sed :/ 
I am using: "sed (GNU sed) 4.8"

I get an error with all three of your solutions:
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

I am using a capitol E, but still get that error. I tried an older version of sed, but I get the same error.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: @Henric see [here](http://tpcg.io/_O0PQ9P)

Comment: It works great in Linux and I am impressed, but in a windows command line environment, I cannot get it to work. I tried replacing single quotes with double quotes , and / with |  (I have read that could help). Unfortunately, it did not help. 
Your code is correct for sure but I now have to find "tricks" to get the code to work in Windows.